# Indian tourist visa extension for USA citizen (8 month old baby)

Tags: india, us-citizens, tourist-visas

My baby is a USA citizen, travelled to India on tourist visa(valid till 2023).We wanted to extend his stay in India for more than 180 days. Does anyone has extend the tourist visa online?
when we try to extend the stay in online(frro website) below are the options showing. Not sure which option to select for the stay extension[image]

Comment: Is the baby not eligible for OCI (overseas citizenship of India) or a different visa class? What's your situation? Is this a paper tourist visa or some sort of e-visa?

Also page 4 of https://www.mha.gov.in/PDF_Other/AnnexIII_01022018.pdf says that tourist visas cannot be extended.

Comment: He is eligible for oci card but due to emergency we made him travel.So now we want to extend his stay for more than 6months please let us know which option can we choose to apply for stay extension.He is now on paper based tourist visa which is valid till 2033.

Comment: Not sure on how good of an idea it is, but would it be possible to do a visa run (this means visiting a neighbouring country for a few days, and then returning back to India)? You can't extend a tourist visa in India.